# Combining jQuery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this http://jsfiddle.net/Stocki/jGbhh/

and changed to this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".slides", function () {
    $(".slide").removeClass("inside");
    $("#" + this.id + "_slide").addClass("inside");
});

$(document).on("click", ".close", function () {
    $(".slide").removeClass("inside");
});
```

It works perfectly, but it doesn't seem right. I feel it should be more of a on click `.slides` or `.close` then `removeClass` else on click `addClass`.

Any help would be appreciated. This is my first attempt and I'd really like to understand why/how it works and how that should be written so I'm not using `$(document)` twice.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, jQuery will use addEventListener for each element internally any way.

Comment: The way you have it looks good to me, I wouldn't change a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a multiple selector and split up the flow inside the event handler by means of the class that the current element is having,

```
$(document).on("click", ".slides,.close", function(){
  $(".slide").removeClass("inside");
  if($(this).hasClass('slides')){
     $("#"+this.id+"_slide").addClass("inside");
  }
});
```

Comment: @matt Your edit must be the correct way of doing this, but using .is() also correct.. right?

Comment: Raj: Was just posting a comment to explain ;). `is()` will also work, but `hasClass()` is quicker (http://jsperf.com/is-vs-hasclass)

Comment: @Matt Thnks for the valuable info.. :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Thanks! That makes sense. I have just started working with jQuery and with the little bit of php I know my thought process wanted to do it the way you helped me with.